# I can't get the value of the sweet alert variable in the final alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert

I have a problem. I am trying to launch a sweet alert, and that this value that the user writes in the input, comes out in an alert at the end.

What I do at the beginning is to check if a class called "agregarCarrito" exists. If it exists, execute the sweet alert and if not, take the value that contains an element with that class. At the end, it shows the value of the obtained variable. In the case of the sweet alert it does not work

I do not understand why it does not work. Can someone give me help?

I leave the code

```
$(".agregarCarrito").click(function() {

    var cantidadPedida;

    if(!$(".cantidadBoton")[0]){

        swal({
              title: "¿Cuántas unidades?",
              text: "Escribí el número de unidades que necesitás",
              type: "input",
              showCancelButton: !0,
              closeOnConfirm: !1,
              cancelButtonText: "Cancelar",
              confirmButtonText: "Confirmar",
              animation: "slide-from-top",
              inputPlaceholder: "Sólo se permiten números"
        }).then(function(inputValue){

            var expresion =  /^[0-9]{1,3}$/;

            if (inputValue === false) return false;

            if (inputValue === "") {
                swal.showInputError("¡Te falta aclarar la cantidad!");
                return false
            }

            if (!expresion.test(inputValue)) {
                swal.showInputError("¡Sólo se permiten números!");
                return false
            }  

            cantidadPedida = inputValue;
            alert(cantidadPedida);

        });

    } else {

        cantidadPedida = $(".cantidadBoton").val();

    }

    alert(cantidadPedida);

})
```

Comment: First, I don't see any checks for a class "addCarito". Second, can you explain further what you mean by "it does not work"? What is it that doesn't work?

Comment: @ehymel Sorry, when translating the text was in English, but it is "agregaCarrito". What I'm trying to say is that when you execute the sweet alert "swal ({...", the user writes a value in the input, the final alert is not executed with the value of that input